# How to convert a varchar to datetime from a View

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a View with date data in varchar in my column. i just want to convert and update all of my date in datetime.`

```
update temp_vertical_dashboard
set data = convert (datetime,data,101)
```

"temp_vertical_dashboard"-----> VIEW 
"data"----------> COLUMN WITH VARCHAR TYPE

Comment: i am using sql server

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an actual column of type varchar in a table:

- Create a new column of type datetime
- Convert the varchar data to datetime in the new column
- Delete the old column
- Rename the new column
- Adjust *everything* which assumed varchar instead of datetime for that column.

Comment: yes but for creating a new column of type date time i have to create into my table that refer my view.but this table has many join that i ain't where to start.

Comment: @Kelvin You will need a copy of the database to work on and a set of tests which covers everything so that you can be sure that everything that needs to be updated is updated.